# Phrase to describe a movement

Tags: phrases

How do you describe in a phrase the movement of something that you may see through the corner of your eye ? Like a slight movement that the corner of your eye may catch ?

Comment: A *peripheral movement*, a *glimpse*?

Comment: thanks for this. A glimpse is I think like a proper look at something. But what I mean is that you are looking in one direction and probably focusing on one object but then you spot a movement of an object you were not really focusing on but catch it somehow like from the corner of your line of sight ? sorry this is my first time here if its too long a question. apologies LOL

Comment: the typical idiom is *i caught X out of the corner of my eye*, not sure if there's a dedicated word for it.

Comment: Yep, saw/caught/glimpsed out of the corner of my eye.

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase that I think you will like:

*peripheral vision*

Wikipedia's simple English site [says](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periphery):

> Peripheral vision is that part of visual perception that occurs in the periphery, i.e., near the edges, of the field of view.

Example: "My peripheral vision caught a slight movement and I turned to take a closer look."

Answer (score 1):

***flicker***, [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flicker)

> a brief occurrence or appearance

Example, made up:

> From the corner of my eye, I caught a flicker of  movement in the 
>   trees, and then the bobcat was gone.